# Slick not running

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

I am developing an HTML template, I do need slick to handle a testimonials carousel, but even if I point the div ID with slick nothing happen.

I got no errors in the console.

This is the code I am using:

---- HTML ----

```
<section id="testimonials">
<h2 class="text-center text-uppercase margin-bottom-3">testimonials</h2>
<div class="row is-full">
    <div class="columns large-8 medium-8 hide-for-small-only nopadding">
        <img src="assets/img/testimonials-bg.jpg" alt="placeholder"/>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-12 bg-odd rel" id="tSlider">
        <div class="text-center margin-3">
            <img src="assets/img/test1.jpg" class="testimonial is-rounded" alt="test1">
            <h5 class="text-capitalize">john doe</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusantium aliquam at deserunt dignissimos doloribus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center margin-3">
            <img src="assets/img/test1.jpg" class="testimonial is-rounded" alt="test1">
            <h5 class="text-capitalize">john doe</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusantium aliquam at deserunt dignissimos doloribus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center margin-3">
            <img src="assets/img/test1.jpg" class="testimonial is-rounded" alt="test1">
            <h5 class="text-capitalize">john doe</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusantium aliquam at deserunt dignissimos doloribus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
```

---- JS ----

```
$(document).on(ready, function(){
    $('#tSlider').slick({
        infinite: true,
        autoPlay: true,
        dots: true,
        autoPlaySpeed: 3500
    });
});
```

Comment: What errors do you see in console?

Comment: I have no errors, the only error I have is for the favicon because is not in the files yet. In fact I can't understand why is not working if no error appear.

Comment: Does `$('#tSlider')` running in console find your dom element?

Comment: fixed, thanks anyway ;)

Comment: please, tell us what was the issue

Comment: it was the ready, I had to change this: $(document).on(ready, function(). to this: $(document).ready(function().  I was looking at the console with firefox and I had not a single error, when I switched to chrome the error came up. I dont know why it was not working with the old code because it's the same that the dev show in the docs.

Comment: AFAIK `$(document).ready` is deprecated, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: the last one, I am using google hosted libraries